# Sinon Spy not called but original function is called

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, supertest, sinon-chai

My spy is not being called, even though I can see the console log in the original function getting called

Mocha test:

```
const { expect } = require('chai');
const supertest = require('supertest');
const MyController = require('../../Controllers/MyController');
const sandbox = require('sinon').createSandbox();
const app = require('../../app');

describe('GET /endpoint', () => {
    it('calls handler', (done) => {
        const mySpy = sandbox.spy(MyController, 'handler');

        supertest(app)
            .get('/endpoint')
            .expect(() => {
                expect(mySpy.called).to.be.true;
            })
            .end(done);
    });
});
```

Express controller:

```
function handler(request, response) {
    console.log('I can see this method being called');
    return response.sendStatus(200);
}

module.exports = {
    handler
};
```

Express router:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const MyController = require('../Controllers/MyController');

router
    .get('/endpoint', MyController.handler);

module.exports = router;
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: There is a typo in your Mocha test, line 3, you wrote Controler with one L

Comment: thank you @PatrickHund - it was me simplifying the code before posting it here.  it is unrelated to the issue though

Comment: OK, are the paths correct, though? in the router, you are requiring MyController without any path, in the test with "../"

Comment: Thanks, fixed, but again - unrelated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these lines of code:

```
router
    .get('/endpoint', MyController.handler)
```

...you're passing the actual function defined on `MyController.handler`. What `router.get()` got was simply a reference to that function.
When you later, in the test, wrap `MyController.handler` in a spy, that doesn't change the fact that `router.get()` has a separate reference to the original function.

What you need to do is to make sure that the route handler always invokes `MyController.handler()`. Change the expression into this:

```
router
    .get('/endpoint', () => MyController.handler())
```